# how a client connect to server in Java RMI?

Tags: java, permissions, rmi, accesscontrolexception

[image]I am developing a simple phone book application in in RMI. I am able to start RMI registry and stub class is also generated for the Implementation c1ass. Now i have started the server by using command Java PhoneBookServer in my cmd prompt. The next step is to start the client,So after the i started the client the following error arises! Both the client and servers programs are in a single folder [image]

The code i used so far for client and server are as follows

```
     import java.rmi.*;
     import java.rmi.server.*;

     public class PhoneBookServer {
     public static void main  (String[] args){

    /*Create and install a security manager

      SecurityManager appsm = System.getSecurityManager();
          if(appsm==null){

          System.setSecurityManager(new RMISecurityManager()); 

       }*/

       System.out.println("Server is started");

     try
      {
        //create PhoneBookImpl
        PhoneBookImpl Pb=new PhoneBookImpl();
        Naming.rebind("rmi://127.0.0.1:1099/PhoneBook", Pb);
      }
        catch(Exception e)
       {
          System.out.println("Exception is:" +e);
     }

     }

    }
```

Client Program

```
     import java.rmi.*;
     import java.rmi.registry.*;
     import java.rmi.server.*;
     import java.lang.*;
     import java.io.*;
     import java.util.Scanner;

     public class PhoneBookClient {
     public static void main  (String[] args) throws Exception
     {

      /*Create and install a security manager

          SecurityManager appsm = System.getSecurityManager();
          if(appsm==null){
                  System.setSecurityManager(new RMISecurityManager()); 

       }*/

      String name,number,total,choice,id;
      String ch;
      PhoneBook pb=(PhoneBook)Naming.lookup("rmi://127.0.0.1:1099"+"/PhoneBook");
      Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("1.Enter new record /n");
      System.out.println("2.Look up record /n");
      System.out.println("3.Delete record /n");
      System.out.println("Enter your option");
      ch=in.nextLine();

      if(ch.equals("1")){
      do{
         System.out.println("Enter unique id:");
         id=in.nextLine();
         System.out.println("Enter name:");
         name=in.nextLine();
         System.out.println("Enter phone number:");
         number=in.nextLine();
         total=name+"  "+number;
         pb.new_record(id,total);
         System.out.println("Enter 'q' to quit or enter 'p' to proceed");
         choice=in.nextLine();
         }while(!choice.equals("q"));

       }
      if(ch.equals("2")){
         do{
          System.out.println("Enter id to look up a record"+"  enter 'q' to quit");
          id=in.nextLine();
          String record=pb.lookup_record(id);
          System.out.println("The record is" +record);
          }while(!id.equals("q"));
                      }

     if(ch.equals("2")){
        do{
          System.out.println("Enter id to delete a record"+"  enter 'q' to quit");
          id=in.nextLine();
          pb.lookup_record(id);
          System.out.println("The record is deleted");
        }while(!id.equals("q"));

                   }
         }
      }
```

Previously i got the exception:

```
Connection refused to the host127.0.0.1 access denied.
```

So I install the security mnager in my client and server programs. Now I get this new type of exception. How can I solve the problem.

Comment: You can see the error in the cmd prompt by clicking on the "enter image description" in the question above

Comment: What new exception? What problem? Post the exception, and the code, *here.* Most people won't bother to follow links, and the question has no permanent value unless it contains all the relevant material.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427473/java-rmi-accesscontrolexception-access-denied

Comment: 1 - assign the policy file correctly, either with a commandline flag:
java -Djava.security.policy=/home/.../<filename>.policy .... .My all java files are in C:/java/PhoneBook folder. How to ssign policy file for my java files?

Comment: 2 - make sure the format of the policy file is correct, e.g.:
'grant codeBase "file:<path>/bin/-" {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
};'.Where i have to type the above code?

Comment: could you help me how to assign policy file for my project. all files are in c:/java/PhoneBook folder and also the how to get permission. 
@KevinPanko

Comment: Don't use a security manager, don't use a policy file, don't specify a policy file, do not pass GO, do not collect $200.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the security manager. You don't need it in this configuration. Get rid of *both* security manager installs in the server: you can only install one; and get rid of it in the client too.

I don't see how that server code can possibly work at all with the two security managers. That can't be the real code.

Comment: i removed one Security manager in both client and server. now i get an exception when i started the server: java PhoneBookServer '      java.security.AccessControlException: access denied
  (java.net.SocketPermission 127.0.0.1:1099 connect,resolve)'

Comment: Yon can only get that exception if there is a security manager installed. I did specifically say to remove *both* in the server.

Comment: first i tried without any security manager,then the server showed the error access denied, then i installed the security manager so that it might connect, but still it shows the same exception

Comment: No you didn't. It is impossible for the server to show 'access denied' without a security manager. Look at your own stack trace. The `AccessException` is thrown via the `SecurityManager.`

Comment: i get the following exception when i started the server without any security manager 'java.rmi.connectException: connection refused to host 127.0.0.1;nested exception is java.net.connectException:connection timed out'.

Comment: i could have updated the exception image but the edit option is not working

Comment: I tried with and without security manager, Either way the server is not starting, could anybody please help to solve the problem. Is there any body who could provide the solution????

Comment: You have a network problem in your host. Nothing to do with RMI. Can you ping 127.0.0.1? Investigate that.