# Error in main - java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "127.0.0.1:1099" "connect,resolve")

Tags: java, rmi

I've been trying to run an RMI example but have been getting the above error on both linux and windows. I have seen people with same problem online but in different situations.

My server class is:

```
import java.rmi.*;
import java.rmi.server.*;

public class CityServerImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements CityServer {

    CityServerImpl() throws RemoteException {
        super();
    }

    public String getCapital(String country) throws RemoteException {
        System.out.println("Sending return string now - country requested: " + country);

        if (country.toLowerCase().compareTo("usa") == 0)
            return "Washington";
        else if(country.toLowerCase().compareTo("ireland") == 0)
            return "Dublin";
        else if (country.toLowerCase().compareTo("france") == 0)
            return "Paris";
        return "Don't know that one!";
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            System.setSecurityManager(new RMISecurityManager());
            System.out.println("Security manager set");

            CityServerImpl cityServer = new CityServerImpl();
            System.out.println("Instance of City Server created");

            Naming.rebind("Capitals", cityServer);
            System.out.println("Name rebind completed");
            System.out.println("Server ready for requests!");
        } catch(Exception exc) {
            System.out.println("Error in main - " + exc.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

I put the interface, CityServer class and my client class into a folder and put the following into the terminal.

```
javac -cp . *.java
rmic CityServerImpl
rmiregistry &
java CityServerImpl
```

And I get back:

```
Security manager set
Instance of City Server created
Error in main - java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "127.0.0.1:1099" "connect,resolve")
```

The 'Naming.rebind("Capitals", cityServer);' appears to be the problem. I have found mentions of a policy file but I have been told that this should run fine without one. Both the client and server would be running on the same PC. Any idea on how to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

You defined the `RMISecurityManager`, but you did not grant yourself permissions to execute the code. You can define a policy as specified [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/PolicyFiles.html) and pass that in one of the two ways.

1. java -Djava.security.policy=`<path>`
2. set this your code 
   `System.setProperty("java.security.policy","<path>");`

I recommend reading [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/TOC.html) from oracle.

This should be a duplicate of an [old question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427473/java-rmi-accesscontrolexception-access-denied)