# Kotlin Remote Method Invocation access denied

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to implement RMI with Kotlin but I am getting the following error. It does not seem to be obeying my server.policy

```
Server exception: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "127.0.0.1:1099" "connect,resolve")
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "127.0.0.1:1099" "connect,resolve")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:472)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:884)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkConnect(SecurityManager.java:1051)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:584)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:148)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:342)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.rebind(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.Naming.rebind(Naming.java:177)
    at Task2Server$Companion.main(Task2Server.kt:24)
    at Task2Server.main(Task2Server.kt)
```

This is the server code

```
class Task2Server {
    companion object {
    val name = "task2server"
    val url = "//localhost/$name"
    @JvmStatic
    fun main(args: Array<String>) {

        if (System.getSecurityManager() == null) {
            System.setSecurityManager(SecurityManager())
        }


        try {
            val graphSearcher: GraphSearcher = SearcherImpl()
            LocateRegistry.getRegistry(Registry.REGISTRY_PORT)
            Naming.rebind(url, graphSearcher)
            println("Server is ready")
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            System.err.println("Server exception: " + ex.toString());
            ex.printStackTrace()
            System.exit(0)
        }
    }

    }
}
```

These are my vmoptions in IntelliJ

```
-Djava.rmi.server.codebase=file:.\graphSearcher.jar 
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost -Djava.security.manager 
-Djava.security.policy=server.policy
```

Finally this is my policy

```
grant codeBase "file:*" {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

[My Project Structure if it is of use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFg7M.png)

Comment: Your policy doesn't allow sockets?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java RMI AccessControlException: access denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427473/java-rmi-accesscontrolexception-access-denied)